# display undefined value in text box without any operation

Tags: php, browser-cache

In my PHP registration page, the "last name" and "password" text boxes are automatically filled in when I redirect to this page. These values are the same as the ones I previously inserted in my database. I have now deleted these values from my database. However, the reg page is still showing the undefined values in the last name and password text boxes every time. How can I stop this from happening?

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 191px">

        <input name="lname" style="height: 22px; width: 230px" type="text" placeholder="LastName"/>
    </td>
    <td class="error" style="width: 549px">&nbsp;
      <?php
        if(isset($errors["lname"]))
        {
          echo $errors["lname"];
        }
      ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 191px">

        <input name="pwd" style="width: 230px; height: 22px" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 549px" class="error">&nbsp;
      <?php
        if(isset($errors["pwd"]))
        {
           echo $errors["pwd"];
        }
      ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i need my all textbox will clear when i open the page

Comment: tryed put value = "" in input tag?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is here. You have a placeholder set for the fields, but I guess that's not your problem. The most likely solution as I see it is that you have saved some previous value to be filled in automagically by your browser.

Comment: no this is occure only today without any editing,yesterday everything was good..my friendd told me erase the cookie but still this problem is not solve.n i already done the value=""

Comment: what was your problem?would you like to say?

Comment: I got the answer sir.it was a browser problem

Answer (score 0):

I think  it is browser caching problem..At first you have to  check your project  which one you have  run.Maybe you was running another one.At first you sure  about your project  after  that  you have to clear your browsing history...Or you can try **incognito mode** of browser ..Because  incognito  mode do not save any history...I think Your good is good ... After that I hope Your code is running well.

Your code running very well in my side.So i think problem is your Browser side.